# ¿Cómo usar keyup en múltiples inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ejemplo de Jquery:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.demostracion', function () {
    alert("Funciona");
});
```

Hay varios inputs que tienen la clase `demostracion`. Estoy tratando que la funcion ejecute en cualquiera de esos inputs al agregar datos (por eso el `keyup`) pero actualmente solo ejecuta en un solo input (el ultimo) con la clase `demostracion` y no encuentro manera de hacerlo...
Agradezco mucho su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez hables de la palabra reservada `$(this)` para detectar el elemento en curso.

Ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <input type="text" class="demostracion">
    <input type="text" class="demostracion">
    <input type="text" class="demostracion">
    <input type="text" class="demostracion">
    <input type="text" class="demostracion">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on('keyup', '.demostracion', function() {
            console.log($(this).val());
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Pese a que tu respuesta no resolvió mi problema, me hizo ver una  manera mejor para dar con una solución, tengo como el 50% de la solución xD. Gracias!

Comment: Es que no fuiste del todo claro, solo entendí que necesitabas eso. Pero por nada ;)

Comment: Es que puse un ejemplo de lo que necesitaba, mas no lo que necesitaba específicamente por que... No xD. Pero, de hecho, debo aceptar tu respuesta ya que si es exacta para la pregunta